# Could not convert string 'Log4netFactory' to a type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, integration, log4net, aspnetboilerplate, castle

I recently updated ABP packages in  my project with this line of code in NuGet console:

```
ForEach($project in get-project -all) {
 ForEach($package in Get-Package -ProjectName $project.ProjectName | ?{ $_.Id -like 'Abp*'}) {
  Update-Package -ProjectName $project.ProjectName -Id $package.Id;} }
```

But when I start the project, I faced this error:

> An exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.ConverterException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Could not convert string 'Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.Log4netFactory,Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration,Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' to a type.

That occurs in this line of code in `Application_Start`:

```
AbpBootstrapper.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
    f => f.UseLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
);
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Abp.Castle.Log4Net Package. see [document](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Logging#abpcastlelog4net-package)

Answer (score 0):

create that function and call it from error line

```
    LogConfig("log4net.config");
```

---

```
   private void LogConfig(string configFileName)
    {
        var log4NetConfig = System.IO.Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, configFileName);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(log4NetConfig))
            AbpBootstrapper.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
                f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig(log4NetConfig)
            );
    }
```

see this answer https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2611#issuecomment-337471760